# Reset user passwords in Laravel framework

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm trying to implement the password reminder according to this:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security

I used the artisan commands :

```
php artisan auth:reminders-table

php artisan migrate
```

and added this to my routes:

```
Route::controller('password', 'RemindersController');
Route::get('forgotpassword', 'RemindersController@getRemind');
```

so now when I go to this page : `myapp/forgotpassword` 
I get the `password.remind` view

which has the following code:

```
<?php include_once(app_path()."/includes/header.php"); ?>

<form action="{{ action('RemindersController@postRemind') }}" method="POST">
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="Send Reminder">
</form>

<?php include_once(app_path()."/includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

when i get to this page and i click on the submit form i get a  `NotFoundHttpException` error, this error happens also if i change the action in the form to other functions.. is there something wrong with my routes? or with my syntax for calling a function from a controller?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
Route::get('forgotpassword', 'RemindersController@getRemind');
```

into

```
Route::post('forgotpassword', 'RemindersController@getRemind');
```

That's because you use POST method to send form.

But it seems you use the same controller method both for GET and POST, so you probably need in this case:

```
Route::match(['GET','POST'], 'forgotpassword', 'RemindersController@getRemind');
```

Comment: i edited a mistake i had in the form, instead of action('RemindersController@getRemind' it should be action('RemindersController@postRemind , its a different function in the same controller.

the get remind function has only this line: return View::make('password.remind'); and chanding the route from get to post gives me a methotnotallowed error