# Password reset laravel 4.2 with Token

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel and I making some test on a system which use version 4.2. I'm trying to follow [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#password-reminders-and-reset) for password reset. So far I'm able to post my email for password reset and I get token on my email.

When I open the URL from email with the token I get this error:

> exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException'

The url is: http://example.com/reset/20e2535a11f7c88d1132c55c752a3a8569adbf5f

This is my route

```
Route::get('/password', ['uses' => 'RemindersController@getRemind']);
Route::get('/reset', ['uses' => 'RemindersController@getReset']);
```

This is in `RemindersController`

```
public function getReset($token = null)
{
    if (is_null($token)) App::abort(404);

    return View::make('site.reset')->with('token', $token);
}
```

And the form from the doc's

```
<form action="{{ action('RemindersController@postReset') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
    <input type="submit" value="Reset Password">
</form>
```

I understand the error.. it is saying that the path/file isn't found but it is there..

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241969/reset-password-without-token-in-laravel-4-2

Comment: @Blueblazer172 I want to use token..

Comment: then look [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-a-password-reset-token/replies/90648) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26362002/5930557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your html form, there is the `action()` method called `RemindersController@postReset`:

```
<form action="{{ action('RemindersController@postReset') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
    <input type="submit" value="Reset Password">
</form>
```

but your route uses `GET`. You have to use `POST`
change your route from:

```
Route::get('/reset', ['uses' => 'RemindersController@getReset']);
```

to:

```
Route::post('/reset', ['uses' => 'RemindersController@getReset']);
```

i think you could use this way. its maybe better:

```
Route::match(['GET','POST'], ['uses' => 'RemindersController@getRemind']);
```

**Update:** Route should have also `token` in it because the url is `/reset/token`:

```
Route::get('/reset/{token}', ['uses' => 'RemindersController@getReset']);
```

Comment: But my reset.blade is in `/site/` not in /`auth/`

Comment: @VLS try to change it to auth and then try again

Comment: I will just for a test.. but I don't want it there.

Comment: This time with Route::match I've got: `'Missing argument 3 for Illuminate\Routing\Router::match(),...`

Comment: Maybe you add some wrong routes. try the oder one: `Route::post('/reset', ['uses' => 'RemindersController@getReset']);`

Comment: the route controller should look like this: `Route::controller('/auth', 'AuthController');`

Comment: Where `Route::controller('/auth', 'AuthController');` this should be?

Comment: before your other controllers

Comment: I don't understand why I need AuthController.. I have user controller in which I have login/register etc which they works perfectly

Comment: yeah so add them to your reset token page

Comment: @VLS here is a detailed axplanaition: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23594166/5930557

Comment: Okay. I have file gallery in `views/site/gallery.blade.php` and route `Route::get ('/gallery', ['uses' => 'HomeController@gallery']);` this one works perfectly when open `http://example.com/gallery` then I have file `views/site/reset.blade.php` which should open when I load ``http://example.com/reset` but it doesn't. Same structure ..

Comment: Found it. I knew it was something silly. I'm trying to open `/reset/TOKEN` but the route is `/reset/` ... When I've added token to route like: `Route::get('/reset/{token}', ['uses' => 'RemindersController@getReset']);` it's loaded.

Comment: Will accept answer for quid me to here. Also for the get/post routes.

Comment: @VLS fine :) you can edit my answer so that other people with the same problem find that

Comment: @VLS thanks for that :) if there is something you can add me to a chat

Comment: Not really. Issue is fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check if your default controller or default security controller isn't loaded somewhere and it doesn't not overwrite the 'reset' route, get in your application directory using command line and type:

```
php artisan routes
```

This should show you if your route is registered and to which controller/action.

Comment: I don't have access to ssh terminal and can't run the command